# Error trying to run PowerBuilder.Net 12.5

Tags: .net, powerbuilder, powerbuilder.net

I get the following error when trying to run PowerBuilder.Net 12.5 after a fresh install on a machine that had Visual Studio 2015 already installed on it...

> The application has failed to start because its side-by-side
>   configuration is incorrect.  Please see the application event log or
>   use the command-line sxstrace.exe tool for more detail.

[image]

Digging into the `Application Event Log` I see this...

- Source: SideBySide
- Event ID: 33

> Activation context generation failed for "C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Sybase\PowerBuilder 12.5\pbshell.exe". Dependent Assembly
>   debuggerproxy.dll,processorArchitecture="X86",type="win32",version="1.0.0.0"
>   could not be found. Please use sxstrace.exe for detailed diagnosis.

I would like to note that I can run `PowerBuilder Classic 12.5` just fine with no errors.  It's just on the `PowerBuilder .NET 12.5` that I'm having this issue.

Answer (score 0):

From the looks of your error message **PowerBuilder is not finding a dependent 32-bit assembly**.

You'll probably need to install the **Visual Studio shell** via the **PowerBuilder.NET installation**. I doubt that PowerBuilder.NET 12.5 is compatible with Visual Studio 2015 because it is too new but if you experiment you might get lucky and make it work.

You could *try* to to install the PB.NET components from the install disk and then inspect the components and try making VS2015 compatible. I'd be surprised if it works though.

PB.NET was a little **behind the most recent .NET Framework** for obvious reasons, so you'd need to have the right .NET version installed and the 32-bit assemblies.

PB Classic uses the classic IDE and not the Visual Studio command shell so that's why it works.